# Passing JSP Parameters, then checking if they exist

Tags: java, jsp, parameters, conditional-statements, parameter-passing

I have a situation, where I am working with multiple JSP includes, and in the root file that calls these includes I am setting a list of parameters. But there are, in some instances where not all of the parameters are used, so the parameters are never set.  I would like to create a conditional statement that checks if the parameter is set, and if not, then don't display its placeholder at all.  Here's my code:

index.jsp

```
<jsp:include page="include.jsp">
     <jsp:param name="title" value="Title of Product"/>
     <jsp:param name="instructor" value="Some Donkus"/>
     <jsp:param name="artist" value=""/>
     <jsp:param name="album" value=""/>
</jsp:include>
```

include.jsp

```
<ul>
<c:if test="${!empty param.title}">
     <li class="instructor">Title:&nbsp;<span><%= request.getParameter("title") %></span></li>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${!empty param.instructor}">
     <li class="instructor">Instructor:&nbsp;<span><%= request.getParameter("instructor") %></span></li>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${!empty param.artist}">
     <li class="instructor">Artist:&nbsp;<span><%= request.getParameter("artist") %></span></li>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${!empty param.album}">
     <li class="instructor">Album:&nbsp;<span><%= request.getParameter("album") %></span></li>
</c:if>
</ul>
```

Current Result:

- **Title:**     Title of Product
- **Instructor:**     Some Donkus
- **Artist:**
- **Album:**

I can get the include.jsp to populate correctly, but even though **ARTIST** and **ALBUM** are blank, their list items still show up.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Since you're using JSTL, get rid of the scriptlet `<%= request.getParameter("title") %>`. Should be `${param.title}` or `<c:out value="${param.title}"/>` (This is an aside, doesn't fix your issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that all you have in your `include.jsp` file? If yes, then add this to the top of the file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

The `jsp` prefix is predefined but JSTL's `c` prefix is not.

Your server might not recognize `<c:if>`s as server side tags (because of the missing `taglib` directive) and for that reason not evaluate them.

So they are sent "as is" to the browser. The browser itself will ignore them (since they are not HTML) but render everything else, including the `<li>`s for artist and album.